# Php upload to Facebook without Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to do a form to upload photos with name and description, but I want to upload the photo at the same time to a Facebook fanpage, with the same form. I don't want to login to facebook before uploading the image, I just want to write the credentials in the php and work with this. I have tried it but I can't get the facebook session (and I don't even know that if is possible to do this without login).

Thanks in advance

```
<?php  

//PAGE ID: ********

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';


require_once( 'complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );

// Make sure to load the Facebook SDK for PHP via composer or manually
require_once( 'complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

session_start();
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('********', '******');

if($session) {

  try {
    // uploading image to user timeline using facebook php sdk v4
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'source' => new CURLFile('img/h_index.jpg', 'image/jpg'), // photo must be uploaded on your web hosting
        'message' => 'User provided message'
        )
      )
    )->execute()->getGraphObject();
    if($response) {
      echo "Photo is uploaded...";
    }

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}

else
{
  echo "no entra en session;";
}
```

Comment: You have registered a Facebook App have you?

Comment: Yes, it's registered. Got my app ID and app secret, they are right on FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('********', '******'); .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works:
To get the access token you can get it from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

```
$session = new FacebookSession('Token');
```

Comment: I have tried that, replacing the Token with the Facebook app token and now I get this error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/complementos/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 74

Answer (score 0):

Finally that worked perfectly! I had another issue, linking the Facebook library. Fixing that and with your fix, it works. Now I get another problem related to permissions. Here it is:
(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

I'll try to get some information about it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/09/facebook-connect-with-php-sdk-v4

Everything is clearly written here. Hope it solves your problem. :)